# check if record exists before saving to db - Rails, Twitter, ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, twitter, rails-activerecord

I am using a [Twitter Gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) to pull and save Tweets from user's timeline. Before saving each `message`, I want to check if this record already exists by comparing the new message's `tweet_id` to the array of `tweet_id`'s already saved in the db. No matter what I try, I am still seeing duplicated records being saved in the `messages` table. Here is what I got:

**Controller call:**

```
@messages = Message.pull_tweets(@user)
```

**"pull_tweets"** method:

```
def self.pull_tweets(user)

    tweets = $twitter.home_timeline  # API call to pull all tweets from the timeline

    if tweets && tweets.each { |tweet| validate_uniqueness_of(user,tweet) }
      tweets.each { |tweet| user.messages.create!(tweet_id: tweet.id ... }
      ...
    else
      ... 
    end
  end
```

**"validate_uniqueness_of"** method:

```
  def self.validate_uniqueness_of(user,tweet)
    if user.messages.pluck(:tweet_id).exclude?(tweet.id.to_s)
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

Comment: you can simply use `validates :tweet_id, uniqueness: true` in your Message model

Comment: Seems like you never know about [exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F) method of ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct cause of your problem is that `tweets.each` will return the `tweets` array, which since it is not nil or false has a truthy value: you're not using the result of your `validate_uniqueness_of` method.

You instead would want to either do something like

```
tweets.all? { |tweet| validate_uniqueness_of(user,tweet) }
```

which returns true only if all the tweets meet your test, or more likey to be what you want

```
if tweets
  tweets = tweets.select { |tweet| validate_uniqueness_of(user,tweet) }
  tweets.each { |tweet| user.messages.create!(tweet_id: tweet.id ... } 
end
```

This would however be rather non idiomatic code. You would usually create a validation on your tweet class and add a unique index on the `tweet_id` column - a uniqueness validation should always be backed up by a unique index or you run the risk of rice conditions.

The validation side of things would look like

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate_uniqueness_of :tweet_id, scope: :user_id #assuming that message belongs_to :user
end
```

You can either keep using create! and rescue the validation exception that will be thrown or switch to `create` which returns true/false depending on what happened. In both cases `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` will be raised if a duplicate slips past the validation

Comment: of course! `tweets.each` would return `true` or would be `truthy`, so everything passed that part would be ignored. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also validate whether the tweet_id is unique based on a :scope parameter:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :tweet_id, scope: :user_id
```